# Textbox to accept values between 1-999 using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have a text box which accepts numeric values between 1-999 using javascript and keypress event has to be used as uswr should not be allowed to enter o in the textbox itself but  say foreg 106 should be an allowed value.currently i am able to resrict 0 then it is not allowing user to enter 0 for later numbers also as it is not allowing to enter 105
i am using icefaces so cannot use html5 here and moreover has to implement using js and using onkeypress event as user shud not be even allowwed to enter the value

Code snippet is as follows which i have used
 onkeypress="if(event.which < 49 || event.which > 57)  return false;

Comment: use `<input type="number" />`, share your code for more assistance

Comment: Hi Saqueib,
Thanks for the quick response.
the code snippet is as onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 49 || event.which &gt; 57)  return false;
i want here that first number to be entered should not be 0, but user should be able to enter 106 or corresponding number involving 0

Comment: make sure that your browser will support html5

Comment: Please put essential information into your question by editing it, not via adding comments. In your question you can also format code by indenting them with 4 spaces.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this will make sure in future that i change in query and not in comments plz reopen so that i can get some inputs.Thanks for the help

Comment: Use this function: `function isMyNumber(evt) {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
             return false;
          }
          var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumber').value+String.fromCharCode(charCode), 10);
          if(num < 1 || num >= 999) {
   var strnum = ''+num;
   document.getElementById('txtNumber').value = strnum.substring(0, strnum.length-1);
            return false;
          }
          return true;
       }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>
     function valid(num){
        res = !isNaN(num)&&num>=1&&num<=999;
        if(!res)
         alert('Please enter a valid number from 1 to 999');
        return res;
      }
    </script>

    <input type='text' onchange='this.value=(valid(this.value)?this.value:"");this.focus();'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JavaScrip, you can use HTML5. Look at that

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999" step="1">
```

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/04-minmaxstep.html

Comment: I am using icefaces n i need to restrict my textbox using js only

Answer (score 0):

Use this function,

```
function isMyNumber(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
             return false;
          }
          var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumber').value, 10);
          if(num < 0 || num > 999) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
       }
```

call like,

```
<input type="text" name="txtNumber" id="txtNumber" onkeypress="return isMyNumber(event);" />
```

Hope this works, thank you.

Comment: What about paste a non numeric value.

Comment: Thanks Balaji for the help.

Comment: As it is stil accepting 0 n if i change the charcode to 49 then not accepting 0 at any level even changed the range from 1-999

Comment: Change if condition from `if(num < 0 || num > 999)`  to `if(num < 1 || num > 999)` and check.

Comment: I already changed the condition but it didnt worked